# How to get sum of values dynamically to different variable in c#

Tags: c#

I have an object (`Details`) which is having employee details. That object has properties (`sal` and `Level`).
I just want to get the sum of `sal` for each and every `Level`.

```
 foreach (var emp in Details)
 {
     int empsal=emp.sal;
     int empLevel= emp.Level;
 }
```

example: I want the sum of all employee sal into different variables based on the levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sumByLevels = Details.GroupBy(employee => employee.Level)
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(x => x.sal));
```

Now assume you want to get total salary of level 1:

```
  var result = sumByLevels[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using LINQ's `GroupBy` method:

```
Dictionary<int, int> sumsByLevel =
    Details.GroupBy(employee => employee.Level, employee => employee.sal).
    ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Sum());
```

This results in a dictionary with the `Level`s as keys and the sum of the corresponding `sal`s as value.

Comment: @CuongLe I rolled back your edit as I think it was causing harm! `group.Sum()` could not work if `group` was an enumeration of employees instead of int.

Comment: Ok, then, see my answer, that's what I wanted to change

Comment: @CuongLe I thought so, but you forgot the lambda in the `Sum`. No problem, give you a +1. I wonder if there would be a performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is good. For example you have class:

```
public class Details
{
     public int Level { get; set; }
     public int Sal { get; set; }
}
```

and you have data:

```
    var data = new List<Details>()
    {
        new Details() {Level = 1, Sal = 1},
        new Details() {Level = 1, Sal = 1},
        new Details() {Level = 1, Sal = 1},
        new Details() {Level = 2, Sal = 2},
        new Details() {Level = 2, Sal = 2},
        new Details() {Level = 3, Sal = 3},
        new Details() {Level = 3, Sal = 3},
        new Details() {Level = 3, Sal = 3},
    };
```

if we calculate, we get:

1. level(1) = 3
2. level(2) = 4
3. level(3) = 9

Solution one (good):

```
    var sum = data.GroupBy(x => x.Level).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, a => a.Sum(b => b.Sal));
    Console.WriteLine(sum[1]); // result 3
    Console.WriteLine(sum[2]); // result 4
    Console.WriteLine(sum[3]); // result 9
```

Solution two (not very good):

```
public int GetSumOfLevel(int level, List<Details> details)
{
    return details.Where(x => x.Level == level).Sum(x => x.Sal);
}
```

...

```
    Console.WriteLine(GetSumOfLevel(1, data)); // result  3
    Console.WriteLine(GetSumOfLevel(2, data)); // result  4
    Console.WriteLine(GetSumOfLevel(3, data)); // result  9
```

May be choose the first option?